# MSVC requires to import DLL for an inline-able compiler-generated constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I got a weird C++ question and have no idea how to resolve it.

I have a public header:

```cpp
// a.h

#ifdef A_EXPORTS
#define A_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define A_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct A_API IWorker
{
    virtual bool foo() { return false; }
};
```

I built `a.DLL` with `-DA_EXPORTS`.

But my `test.exe` just needs a mocked `IWorker`.

```cpp
// test.cpp

#include "a.h"

class CMockWorker : public IWorker
{
public:
    bool foo() override { return true; }
};
```

I built `test.exe`, and found it depends on `a.DLL` because of external symbol `public: __cdecl IWorker::IWorker(void) __ptr64`

I know that `IWorker` has a compiler-generated constructor because of the vtbl, but **could it be inline so we can get rid of `a.DLL`?**

Thanks!

---

As @hans-passant mentioned, yes, once I removed the definition of virtual methods, problem resolved.

```cpp
// a.h

struct IWorker
{
    virtual bool foo() = 0;
};
```

But in existing project, some so-called interface class has similar dummy body and hard to refactor them.

So I really want to find the ideal solution to force-inline the c'tor, if has. Maybe not today, hope it could be impl-ed in the future.

Comment: I don't see any way of doing this without changing the public header file - basically, introducing a third precompiler path where A_API is defined to be empty.

Comment: You can declare IWorker with the [__interface keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/interface?view=msvc-170).  Delete the body of foo and your problem is solved.